# where to start with the X-Men with Marvel NOW! coming up?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I want to get into reading the X-Men. So far, I have no experience with them. Since the X-Men have a very long history, it might be very confusing to get into the story. And I do not want to catch up on very old stories.

I did some googling on the matter and found this guide:

http://www.bigplanetcomics.com/catching-up-with-the-x-men-the-hope-era

My current plan is to read the stories mentioned in that post and take it from there. But then I found out that Marvel wants to reboot their universe with Marvel NOW!

Will this offer an opportunity to get completely fresh X-Men? Or should I do some background reading first? Is there another good starting point for the X-Men?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15429/3804 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13630/3804

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marvel NOW! (As it seems a the moment,) Isn't a reboot, more a continuation but with various titles being cancelled / renumbered.

Note: Beware spoilers when looking at the advance solicitations linked below.

In the [November solicits](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=40453), there are two new titles listed

- All New X-Men (where the original X-Men travel forward to now)
- X-Men: Legacy (based around Professor X's son Legion)

Both seem to be continuation (but that could of course be subject to change, both refer to "the aftermath").

The [previous month](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=39646) had

- Uncanny Avengers (half x-men team, half avengers)

The new titles should be new reader friendly, but will still be tied to the old continuity. There will no doubt be more new titles added as the Marvel NOW! iniative rolls on.

My advice would be to jump in, stick with what you like and leave what you don't. For reading older collections, the library can be a cheap and valuable resources.

Personally, I started reading X-Men when Grant Morrison started writing New X-Men, and tho sometimes hard going, the answers were only a google away.

Comment: +1 | I recommend a large library as a great opportunity to find some of the best collected versions of Marvel's heroes. You get to read the stories that were fan popular (made money) and become the stories future stories will reference.